# How to merge collection data in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, collections

I wan to merge the collection data that I got separately

Example

```
CREATE TYPE VARCHAR_NTT AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50 CHAR);   

select * FROM( (with test_data1 as 
(
select '1' as ID, 'AAA' as NAME, VARCHAR_NTT('AAA') as SUB from dual
union all  select '2', 'BBB', VARCHAR_NTT('AAA','BBB') from dual
union all  select '3', 'CCC', VARCHAR_NTT('AAA','BBB','CCC') from dual
),
test_data2 as 
(
select '4' as ID, 'DDD' as NAME, VARCHAR_NTT('AAA') as SUB from dual
union all  select '5', 'EEE', VARCHAR_NTT('DDD','EEE') from dual
union all  select '1', 'AAA', VARCHAR_NTT('BBB','CCCC','DDD') from dual
union all  select '2', 'BBB', VARCHAR_NTT('FFF','GGG') from dual
)
SELECT  ID,NAME,SUB FROM test_data1
union all SELECT  ID,NAME,SUB FROM test_data2) a);
```

I have some data like how I mentioned above, And I need to Merge that result like below

```
1   AAA APPDATA.VARCHAR_COLL('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD')
2   BBB APPDATA.VARCHAR_COLL('AAA','BBB','FFF','GGG')
3   CCC APPDATA.VARCHAR_COLL('AAA','BBB','CCC')
4   DDD APPDATA.VARCHAR_COLL('AAA')
5   EEE APPDATA.VARCHAR_COLL('DDD','EEE')
```

Basically I need to merge SUB based on ID and NAME

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `MULTISET UNION DISTINCT`:

```sql
WITH test_data1 (id, name, sub) as (
  select '1', 'AAA', VARCHAR_NTT('AAA') from dual union all
  select '2', 'BBB', VARCHAR_NTT('AAA','BBB') from dual union all
  select '3', 'CCC', VARCHAR_NTT('AAA','BBB','CCC') from dual
),
test_data2 (id, name, sub) as (
  select '4', 'DDD', VARCHAR_NTT('AAA') from dual union all
  select '5', 'EEE', VARCHAR_NTT('DDD','EEE') from dual union all
  select '1', 'AAA', VARCHAR_NTT('BBB','CCCC','DDD') from dual union all
  select '2', 'BBB', VARCHAR_NTT('FFF','GGG') from dual
)
SELECT  COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) AS id,
        COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name) AS name,
        COALESCE(t1.sub, VARCHAR_NTT()) MULTISET UNION DISTINCT COALESCE(t2.sub, VARCHAR_NTT()) AS sub
FROM    test_data1 t1
        FULL OUTER JOIN test_data2 t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name
ORDER BY id;
```

Which outputs:

| ID | NAME | SUB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | AAA,BBB,CCCC,DDD |
| 2 | BBB | AAA,BBB,FFF,GGG |
| 3 | CCC | AAA,BBB,CCC |
| 4 | DDD | AAA |
| 5 | EEE | DDD,EEE |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CfXqLu8p)

Comment: From where did you get such advanced concepts?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
Could you please help to merge the result which is one resultset.    
Example :    
1 AAA APPDATA.VARCHAR_NTT('AAA')    
2 BBB APPDATA.VARCHAR_NTT('AAA','BBB')    
3 CCC APPDATA.VARCHAR_NTT('AAA','BBB','CCC')    
4 DDD APPDATA.VARCHAR_NTT('AAA')    
5 EEE APPDATA.VARCHAR_NTT('DDD','EEE')    
1 AAA APPDATA.VARCHAR_NTT('BBB','CCCC','DDD')    
2 BBB APPDATA.VARCHAR_NTT('FFF','GGG')    

I have a one result like above and I need to merge this result based on ID and Name

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I've had to merge collections before and the [Oracle Multiset Operators documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/operators006.htm) gives details of the operators for doing exactly that. There are a few additional things which come from experience (such as the `MULTISET` operators don't work with `NULL` values, which is why `COALESCE` is used to provide an empty collection in that case).

Comment: @ManjunathD It is not clear exactly what you are asking for in your comment but it looks like to need to take exactly the same principal as the answer and apply it to merging your new data.